# How to pass pointer to a parameter of a function in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, parameters

I have a lot of records formed by 4 parameters each one.
I have to create an InsertionSort function with each field of the record, but I have three problems:

1. In first parameter of InsertionSort what can I write in order to pass him the pointer parameter (Is it correct give him directly `struct fields *records`?)
2. I have 4 parameters and I have to order them one by one. But, they're 4 different types and I need a generic InsertionSort. With this configuration, how can I pass those parameters? (I tried to put a generic variable `void* temp` but it doesn't work)
3. Last one, I have to pass 3 parameters in InsertionSort function. One of them (word) is the field that I must use in order to sort my records.

I hope I was clear. If not, tell me in the comment.

**main.c**

```
struct fields{
  int id;
  char field1[20];
  int field2;  
  float field3;
};

int size; //number of records

struct fields *records = malloc(size * sizeof *records);

/* I fill records with my values */

InsertionSort(records, field1, size);   //Here , I need to order my records by field1
```

**InsertionSort function:**

```
void InsertionSort(struct fields *records, char word, int size) {    // point 1 and 3
        int i, j;
        void* temp;   // point 2)
        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            temp = records[i].word;
            j = i - 1;
            while (j >= 0 && records[j].word > temp) {
                records[j + 1].word = records[j].word;
                j--;
            }
            records[j + 1].word = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Were the 3 parameters you need to pass specified, or are you free to choose the type of the parameters?

Comment: No, they are free to choose @meaning-matters

Comment: "I tried to put a generic variable void* temp but it doesn't work" --> Explain more than "it doesn't work".

Comment: What is `.word` in `records[j].word > temp` and what is code trying to accomplish comparing order to a `void *`?

Comment: Each record consists of 4 parameters of different types (id, field1, field2 field3).
With the InsertionSort function call I have to sort these records, once by id, once by field1... (through multiple method calls). However, these parameters are of a different type, so the variable temp in the function cannot always be of the same type, so I thought of putting it generic.
`word` is the parameter by which I want to sort my records: id, fields1, field2, field3. @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: C does not have a generic type.  `void*` is usable as a semi-generic for some pointers in select code.  `InsertionSort()` will needs to receive _something_ to distinguish type of `.word`.  I recommend that you first make 4 variations on  `InsertionSort()` , one per member and then ask "how to make a more generic/flexible? solution".  Research `_Generic`

Comment: Is there a way to understand  type of a variable? @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: Megan "Is there a way to understand type of a variable? "  Yes. As suggested in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64751212/how-to-pass-pointer-to-a-parameter-of-a-function-in-c?noredirect=1#comment114491377_64751212), research `_Generic`.